# How to fix this "Encouraging accidental clicks: Layout"

Tags: admob

I have this issue in admob, do you know how can i fix it?
[image: Encouraging accidental clicks: Layout]

Answer (score 0):

Change the headline from 1 line to 2 lines fix the issue.